# getting "oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out" error

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate, sockets, jdbc

Getting "Socket read timed out" Exception while Connection to oracle database frequently. On restart server and database it works for sometimes but after sometimes it getting again. What is the root cause of below exception.

```
Mar 20, 2018 2:37:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: IO Error: Socket read timed out
Mar 20, 2018 2:37:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc] in context with path [/bl] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection] with root cause
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:321)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
at  oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
at  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at  org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
at com.leafletcorp.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getUserById(UserDaoImpl.java:87)
at com.leafletcorp.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUser(UserServiceImpl.java:563)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at  org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.findUser(Unknown Source)
at com.leafletcorp.web.LoginController.home(LoginController.java:528)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.leafletcorp.sso.ServiceProviderSSOFilter.doFilter(ServiceProviderSSOFilter.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.leafletcorp.interceptors.LogSessionServletFilter.doFilter(LogSessionServletFilter.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It works on restart server but after sometime it throws same exception. Can anybody explain root cause of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your stacktrace, this might be related to incorrect oracle jdbc driver usage. Specific oracle databases versions support only specific oracle jdbc driver versions. More details can be seen here from the oracle website [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01)

Make sure your oracle driver is correct and supported. Also check you are using the right jdk java . Check if your $JAVA_HOME is set. Hope this helps.

Comment: recheck your oracle hostname and ports. how about firewalls in your network ? You might want to look at timeouts configured in the firewall and try and change that

Comment: It could also be a network choke issue. Is process high water count at or near PROCESSES limit? run following sql statements : SQL> select sessions_current, sessions_highwater from v$license; to get highwater mark and increase this value. That might help